# Пунктуация! И как при помощи минимальной правки сделать текст удобочитаемым?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

> Как из сна какого-нибудь падишаха! Тяжеловато сложена, как всякая
>   восточная женщина, точнее, портила её силуэт дурацкая баска на кофте и
>   узкие брюки, но и это неважно – она была прекрасна, как мечта поэта!
>   как утро розы! Её темные волосы, вероятно вымытые в нескольких
>   флаконах этого тягучего аромата, были спрятаны под белой тканью. **Она
>   одновременно и горделиво подставляла лицо свету, и вместе с тем
>   пугливо – стоило задержать лишь на долю секунды внимание, как она
>   прятала его между своим плечом и плечом спутника.** Приём был хорошо
>   отработан и прелестен тем взаимопониманием, которое царило между
>   влюблёнными.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как из сна какого-нибудь падишаха! Тяжеловато сложена, как всякая восточная женщина **(точнее, портила её силуэт дурацкая баска на кофте и узкие брюки),** но и это неважно – она была прекрасна, **как грёзы поэта! как весна в саду!** Её темные волосы, вероятно вымытые в нескольких флаконах этого тягучего аромата, были спрятаны под белой тканью. **Она и горделиво подставляла своё лицо свету, но стоило задержать  на нем внимание, как (пугливо) прятала его между своим плечом и плечом спутника.** Приём был хорошо отработан и прелестен тем взаимопониманием, которое царило между влюблёнными.

Пояснение

Сравнения нужно заменить на что-нибудь. ***Как мечта поэта*** звучит с иронией (есть такой магазин для полных женщин), а ***роза*** — это слишком банальное сравнение. Кстати, ***как сон*** уже было в начале предложения.

Comment: очень хорошая правка. Только почему вы пишете: .... и горделива? Думается, частица ***и*** здесь  не нужна. И частица ли это?

Comment: Спасибо, Серж, за Вашу оценку.  Кстати, союз И был в исходном тексте тоже, он несет вполне определенную нагрузку. По смыслу он  соответствует двойному союзу И...И (и подставляла, и прятала), но в этой конструкции это значение передает сочетание  союзов И, НО, КАК.

Comment: Только в исходном тексте не *и подставляла, и прятала,* а *и горделиво, и пугливо.*

Comment: Я думаю, что это непринципиально. В исправленном тексте  союза И имеет то же значение, то есть значение повторяющегося союза И...И, поэтому союз И мне тоже был нужен. К тому же подставлять лицо и горделиво, и пугливо как-то сложно, лучше разделить эти значения: подставлять горделиво, а прятать пугливо.

Comment: Да, я понял, что Вам он тоже нужен был. И правда, не очень важно, что в исходном И... И. А можете привести примеры с этим И... НО... КАК, а то какие-то они "не свои" (хоть один)? Я верю, что так говорят, но хочется побольше таких начитаться, чтобы привыкнуть к ним

Comment: Артем, мне кажется, что союзные образования такого вида выражают градационные отношения, которые возникают на базе соединительных и сопоставительных отношений. Варианты здесь могут быть разные. Сюда относят всем известные союзы КАК...ТАК И,  НЕ ТОЛЬКО...НО И, а также менее известные ЕСЛИ НЕ...ТО, ХОТЯ И...НО. Ну вот такой пример: Она и хотела бы поехать, но в то же время опасалась чего-то. Без союза И здесь будет простое сопоставление,  а союз И придает дополнительный соединительный оттенок.

Comment: Вот спасибо за такой пример! Он как-то убедительнее прозвучал (знакомым), такие вроде и встречались, и даже сам, возможно, так бы и сказал.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, грёзы поэта и тому подобное мне не по зубам... а вот последнее, может, так?

*Она подставляла лицо свету - одновременно и горделиво, и вместе с тем пугливо: стоило задержать лишь на долю секунды внимание, как она прятала его между своим плечом и плечом спутника.*